# How to code the VBA Macro to allow start a loop each time from a different value of a data validation list

Tags: excel, vba, loops, validation

I am trying to run the same loop for a large validation list . The issue here is that that it always starts from the beginning (or top) of the data validation list, and I would like to start each time I run the macro, from the current selected value in the validation list and go to the next value down to the end.  Any clue is much appreciated!

```
Dim dvCell As Range
 Dim inputRange As Range
 Dim c As Range
 Dim i As Long


 'Which cell has data validation
 Set dvCell = Worksheets("ValperSIS").Range("e20")
 'Determine where validation comes from
 Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)


 i = 1
 'Begin our loop
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each c In inputRange
 dvCell = c.Value

    If Range("CHECKSIS") = False Then
    Exit For
    End If
Sheets("ValperSIS").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Name = Range("e20").Value
On Error GoTo 0
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next c
```

Comment: You will have to provide more details for someone to be able to help you. Maybe a code snippet or some images of your dataset

Comment: How/where do you keep that 'validation list'? What do you like to trigger the code start? Wouldn't it `Worksheet_Change` event be good enough?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i am adding my current code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

Suppose that the list is a named range in column-A called "data" in Sheet1.
[image]

The validation cell is A1 referring to list "=data" in Sheet2. 
[image]

In Sheet2 worksheet module :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
With Sheets("Sheet2")
Set c = .Range("data").Find(Target.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set Rng = .Range(c, c.End(xlDown))
For Each cell In Rng
MsgBox cell.Value 'the code to loop
Next
End With
End If
End Sub
```

When the user choose any item in the cell validation,
the loop will start from the selection to the end, for example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Karma, however I want to "continue" the loop from the last value that I inserted. If I keep the code shown above, it goes back to the very first value of the validation table. Besides I would not like to run the macro automatically by changing the value, just when I order it

Comment: @FGp, you wrote : _"I want to "continue" the loop"_ . So do you mean that : (1) you run a loop (2) you pause that loop (3) you select an item from the validation cell (4) you want that paused loop continue based on your selection. Something like that ?

Comment: About it won't trigger macro once it's selected, it can be done by moving the code to regular module than put a button assigned with that macro. The code I post doesn't pause a loop, waiting to the user input, then continue the loop based on the user input. The code just do the loop where it start based on the item (selected by the user in the validation cell) in the list to the end of the list. Suppose there are 5 rows of data in the list with a value pa pi pu pe po respectively, if the user select pe in validation cell, then the code will loop twice based on pe on row 4 and po on row 5.

Comment: Let me try to explain the way I want this macro to work:i)the Macro starts looping from te top value of a validation list but it stops with an exit code, which is linked to a True-False Check; when the check is false, then the loop stops. My problem is that once it has stopped, evenif the value of the validation list is not the very first one, it goes back up to the first one and halts in the same value that brings the False check. I would like to , after selecting the value manually, ask the macro to loop but starting from that value and go down to the bottom and so on.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I was wrong to get what you mean. In your code `If Range("CHECKSIS") = False`, is your "checksis" named range refer to one cell or more than one cell ? What is it in "checksis" range ? a formula ? I also wonder, how the macro has to run if the user choose the validation value which is "before" his "first" selection ? I mean something like this : the validation has pa pi pu pe po. At first the user select pu ... then he run the macro. The second time he select pi then he run the macro.

Answer (score 0):

Karma, you are right, I want the loop to stop when the "exit for" applies, and what that happens, I wanted to select the new starting value of the validation list till the nest "exit for" stops the loop-